# JavaScript <canvas> draw scaled image

Tags: javascript, graphics, canvas, adobe-illustrator

The amazing Illustrator plugin [Ai->canvas](http://visitmix.com/labs/ai2canvas/) exports arbitrary complex Illustrator images to Javascript code that draws on `<canvas>`. For example, this is the code for a green square 150x150

```
function draw(ctx) {

  // layer4/Path
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(150.0, 150.0);
  ctx.lineTo(0.0, 150.0);
  ctx.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
  ctx.lineTo(150.0, 0.0);
  ctx.lineTo(150.0, 150.0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

This is a stupid example because drawing a square is better done with a rectangle, but anyway, for complex images, this is invaluable. The problem is **scaling**.

How can I transform a generic draw function output by Ai->canvas in order to accept a scale factor? This square example is pretty straight forward, but I'd like something more generic to be applied to a Javascript function drawing on canvas (with arcs, circles, bezier curves...). Thanks

Comment: From this limited example I suspect that you can just multiply numbers with corresponding scale factor. However, I am not familiar with this plugin and didn't see more complex code that it generates. Could you post some?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: For arcs and beziers and such, you start getting into trig rather than simple multiplication.

Comment: Use something like fabric.js which exports SVG's to _objects_, not just a set of commands. By representing canvas drawing in object-oriented fashion, fabric makes it possible to scale, rotate, move, delete, add, duplicate objects, and even export all of that back to SVG at any point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the `scale` function of the canvas, e.g.:

```
ctx.scale(xFactor, yFactor);
```

[More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations)